# How to use `wakeonlan` with a VPN active?

Tags: networking, vpn, wake-on-lan, wireguard, broadcast

Today, I've started using the PIA (Private Internet Access - Version 2.9) VPN service via their native application to set things up, everything works like a charm so far, apart `wakeonlan some-mac-address` to turn on my home server.

I did a lot of digging and setting things differently in the PIA app but to no avail. *Allow LAN Traffic* does not apply here, since we are sending the broadcast to PIA network.

---

I even tried `tcpdump` and obviously the `255.255.255.255` full broadcast address cannot be used even if I put that `wakeonlan` `perl` script on a Split Tunnel along with `perl` binary itself.

---

What do I need to put on *whitelist* (put on split tunnel) or change in my simple command to be able to wake up my server even if on the PIA VPN?

---

I'm using Mint 20.1 Cinnamon and PIA v2.9 on WireGuard with these network settings:

[image: PIA v2.9 on WireGuard - settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least with my current router (Archer AX10), one can do the following (I don't really understand *casts or networking in general, so if it needs further clarification, be my guest and answer yourself.

---

Just insert your local subnet like `192.168.0`**.255**, obviously you need to insert your LAN **!**

```
wakeonlan -i 192.168.0.255 mac-address
```

If you made it work like me, then create your shell's alias like `boot-something`, and your problem is gone.